# How to calculate the Aitchison distance in python

Tags: scipy, statistics

I have compositional data for which I would like to calculate the similarity. As input I have two 1D arrays such as:

```
data1=[0.03510584946878486, 0.09929433687476773, 0.049647168437383864, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.07021169893756972, 0.07021169893756972, 0.024823584218691932, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.024823584218691932, 0.2808467957502789, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.03510584946878486, 0.049647168437383864, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.024823584218691932, 0.024823584218691932]

data2=[0.036891382048211505, 0.29513105638569204, 0.05217229282726804, 0.02608614641363402, 0.018445691024105752, 0.07378276409642301, 0.05217229282726804, 0.02608614641363402, 0.05217229282726804, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.10434458565453608, 0.036891382048211505, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.036891382048211505, 0.036891382048211505, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.018445691024105752]
```

These can be thought of as two different conditions, each with its own probability-per-category. From reading around it seems like Aitchison distance is most appropriate for calculating how similar these are, although I might be wrong. It doesn't seem like Scipy has anything implemented for it. Does anyone know how to do it or have thoughts on how to best compare compositional data?

Comment: Scipy's github contains an issue with [two proposals of implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4480). Following comments seem appropriate: [first](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4480#issuecomment-274993635) and [second](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4480#issuecomment-500261371).

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing that function from the github proposal but couldn't get it to work. These functions were not defined: _validate_vector(..) and norm(..).

Comment: `norm` probably is `scipy.stats.norm`.  `_validate_vector` is a function that generates an error (or warning) for some types of invalid inputs. You can leave it out in your case, or replace it by `u = np.array(u)` to make sure you're working with numpy arrays.